# Synchronization problem while getting data from firebase database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a problem with my Firebase database data retrieve sync. I am able to get data but return works before it. So my data never put in the intended list.

Here is my code:

```
DatabaseManager databaseManager = new DatabaseManager();
MedicineData medicineData = new MedicineData();
boolean validated = false;
private static final String TAG = "BarcodeDecoderDataMatrix";

public Map getDataMatrix(String dataMatrixText) {

    Map<String, Object> dataMatrix = new HashMap<>();
    String barcodeNum = getBarcodeNumber(dataMatrixText);
    String expireDate = getExpireDate(dataMatrixText);
    String serialNum = getSerialNumber(dataMatrixText);
    String partyNum = getPartyNumber(dataMatrixText);

    dataMatrix.put("barcodeNumber",barcodeNum);
    dataMatrix.put("expireDate", expireDate);
    dataMatrix.put("serialNumber", serialNum);
    dataMatrix.put("partyNumber", partyNum);

    getMedicineName(barcodeNum, (success) -> {
        if(success){
            //find the data on database
            dataMatrix.put("medicineName", medicineData.getProductName());
            dataMatrix.put("companyName", medicineData.getCompanyName());
            dataMatrix.put("price", medicineData.getPrice());
        }
        else {
            //can't find on database
        }
    });

    return dataMatrix;
}
```

This method called from another class to get dataMatrix list.

```
    private void getMedicineName(String barcodeNum, SimpleCallback<Boolean> finishedCallback) {

      DatabaseReference rootRef = databaseManager.getReference();
      DatabaseReference medicinesRef = rootRef.child("MedicineList");
      Query queryMedicineNameFinder = medicinesRef.orderByKey().equalTo(barcodeNum);
      ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                medicineData = ds.getValue(MedicineData.class);
            }

            if (medicineData != null){
                validated = true;
            }
            finishedCallback.run(validated);
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
            finishedCallback.run(false);
        }
    };
    queryMedicineNameFinder.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
}
```

These two methods are in the same class called BarcodeDecoderDataMatrix. I create an instance of this class from another class and call getDataMatrix method. I am expecting to get a list include my values. I can get barcodeNum, expireDate, serialNum, partyNum values without a problem. But the list doesn't include medicineName, companyName and price informations. I made a debug so I know I can get data from database. I can see it in medicineData variable. I am pretty sure it is a sync issue. Because my data in medicineData but it can't put it in the list before return called.

How can I make this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`addListenerForSingleValueEvent()` method that you are using in your code, is asynchronous. This means that it returns immediately, while `onDataChange()` method fires only when the results are available.

What you are doing in your code is incorrect because you assuming that the results are immediately available and are not.

When you call `getMedicineName()` method, you should directly use `dataMatrix` in the callback, after the data is known that is available.

For more information, I recommend you see the last part of my anwser from this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47847694/how-to-return-datasnapshot-value-as-a-result-of-a-method/47853774)** in which I have explained how it can be done using a custom callback. You can also take a look at this **[video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OvDZVV5CbQg)** for a better understanding.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried to implement callback Interface already but I learned from your answer I was doing it wrong. So I move it to onDataChange method. And I also make another changes. I updated my question. Could you check again ? It still can't get data on time.

Comment: That seems to be another issue. Please don't edit the question with another question, but post a new question using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you. I just rolled back to the initial question.

Comment: I didn't know I can create MCVE so I do that. Thank you for your help. I figure it out. I changed my code structure. I make class void so it doesn't return. Now it works perfectly. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Good to hear that you make it work and you're very welcome, cheers!